# How can I add a C# assembly reference to an F# project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, reference, f#

There is an assembly written in C# that doubles as a command line EXE. I need to reference this assembly from an F# project. I know nothing of F# and all I need is to replace one line of code with a call to this new assembly.

When I add a reference, I can view it in the object browser and see that its namespace and classes are loaded and recognized.

But when I include a line `open SomeNamespace` for its top level namespace in the project source, I get a compilation error:

> The namespace or module 'SomeNamespace' is not defined

I tested that I can reference and call this C# assembly EXE from a C# project.
Also tested that I can reference a C# assembly residing in a DLL such as `MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel-gdi` from this F# project w/o errors.

Is the syntax for referencing C# from F# different from referencing an F# assembly?

Comment: "*Is the syntax for referencing C# from F# different from referencing an F# assembly?*" No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devil's in the details! The C# assembly was a higher .NET version than the old F# project. Syncing that fixed the issue.